# Bash script to replace a block of PHP Code with another maintaining syntax and characters escaping where necessary

Tags: php, bash, replace, find, ubuntu-14.04

I have a PHP file at location `/var/www/html/siteroot/app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Module/File.php`.

This file contains following code that I need to replace:

```
$this->getUploader()->getConfig()
    ->setUrl(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/image'))
            ->setFileField('image')
            ->setFilters(array(
            'images' => array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
                'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg','*.jpeg', '*.png')
    )
));
```

with following code:

```
$url = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/image');
        if (class_exists("Mage_Uploader_Block_Abstract")) {
            // PATCH SUPEE-8788 or Magento 1.9.3
            $this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig()
                ->setFileParameterName('image')
                ->setTarget($url);
            $browseConfig = $this->getUploader()->getButtonConfig();
            $browseConfig->setAttributes(
                array("accept" => $browseConfig->getMimeTypesByExtensions('gif, png, jpeg, jpg'))
            );
        } else {
            $this->getUploader()->getConfig()
            ->setUrl($url)
            ->setFileField('image')
            ->setFilters(array(
                'images' => array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
                    'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg','*.jpeg', '*.png')
                )
            ));
        }
```

How can I achieve this with maintaining and escaping characters, through a bash script, so that the PHP syntax doesn't break ?

Comment: Why does this need to be done through a bash script?  There are other utilities for patching code.

Comment: Why not just edit the file with a editor?

Comment: I have certain fixes for Magento patch which I want to apply to multiple sites in my local system and maybe to live sites too, if this works well in local system, which would be cumbersome if done manually by editors. Also Magento Developer team uses batch files for patching. If you have any better way, please post, I am open for better suggestions too.

Answer (score 0):

Bash does not have reliable mutiline match tool. You can do it with perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$OLD= <<'EOF';
$this->getUploader()->getConfig()
    ->setUrl(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/image'))
            ->setFileField('image')
            ->setFilters(array(
            'images' => array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
                'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg','*.jpeg', '*.png')
    )
));
EOF


$NEW= <<'EOF';
$url = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/image');
        if (class_exists("Mage_Uploader_Block_Abstract")) {
            // PATCH SUPEE-8788 or Magento 1.9.3
            $this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig()
                ->setFileParameterName('image')
                ->setTarget($url);
            $browseConfig = $this->getUploader()->getButtonConfig();
            $browseConfig->setAttributes(
                array("accept" => $browseConfig->getMimeTypesByExtensions('gif, png, jpeg, jpg'))
            );
        } else {
            $this->getUploader()->getConfig()
            ->setUrl($url)
            ->setFileField('image')
            ->setFilters(array(
                'images' => array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
                    'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg','*.jpeg', '*.png')
                )
            ));
        }
EOF



undef $/;
while (<>) {
s%\Q$OLD%$NEW%m;
print;
}
```

That script is not too clean or safe, but it does what you need. Use like `perl script.pl file.php > newfile.php`